# Как привязать Яндекс карты через ключ, в приложение Unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, api, yandex-maps-api, unity3d-android

Здравствуйте столкнулся с такой проблемой - создаю приложение, у заказчика в требование привязать яндекс карты через ключ, к мобильному приложению Unity3d. В интернете ничего нет, перерыл все форумы.

Прошу помощи и подсказок у знающих людей, всем спасибо заранее, за предоставленную информацию!

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/

Comment: Вы оцените для начала требования заказчика и условия использования API Яндекс Карт. Приложение, вероятно, их нарушает. И тогда api-ключ нужен с платным тарифом. А готов ли заказчик и за это платить тоже? https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/

Comment: В чем проблема? С тем что api на js или отрисовке карты в рендере unity? Програмисты большие проблемы делят на маленькие и решают их по очереди, а если тебе нужен полный и развернутый гайд, то ты дверью ошибся. А вообще заказчик, часто лицо не посвященное и не понимает сложность вещей которые он хочет, а если хотябы приблизительно не понимает и исполнитель... Желко заказчика, ему не повезло.